# Setting a time limit on a slider, only allowing the user to edit within 30 minutes

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im trying to add a time limit to my slider which will only allow the user to update their score within 30 minutes, they can add a score in as many times as they like as it appears in a chart for them, they can view all their previous scores entered but i want to set it so that they can only edit their score within 30 minutes of entering it . Is their any way i can do this perhaps hide my slider if its over 30 etc

```
    async void SubmitFeedback_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CurrentSymptomFeedback.DateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
        CurrentSymptomFeedback.Datetimelimit = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30).ToString();
        ExtendedGrialButton btn = sender as ExtendedGrialButton;
        string UserSymptomID = btn.IDValue;

        if (btn.IDValue != IDofSymptomforAdjusting)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Add feedback", "Please add feedback for the symptom selected", "OK");
        }

        else if (rangeSlider == null)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("Add feedback", "Please add feedback for a symptom", "OK");
        }

        else

        {
            await AddSymptomFeedback(FeedbackID, rangeSlider.Value.ToString(), UserSymptomID);


            await GetSymptomFeedback(CurrentSymptomFeedback.Usersymptomid);

        }

    }
```

Comment: set a timestamp when they add a score, and if they try to edit check the current time against the timestamp, if it if > 30 display an error

Comment: @LeoZhu Yes that did it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it with a timer ,there are two ways to do this.

1. use **Handler** :

   ```
   new Handler().PostDelayed(
          () => { 
                  //do something
                  slider.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone; }, 1800);
   ```
2. use **Timer** :

   ```
   // create a timer object
   Timer _dispatcherTimer;

   //limit time
   int sec = 1800;

   //Instantiate the timer and delegate the event
   TimerCallback timerDelegate = new TimerCallback(Tick);
   _dispatcherTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(timerDelegate,null,0,1000);

   private void Tick(object state)
    {
       this.RunOnUiThread(() =>
       {
         //do something
           if (sec > 0)
           {
               sec--;
           }
           else
           {
               _dispatcherTimer.Dispose();
               slider.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

           }
       });
    }
   ```